# Spectroscopy Spectrometry Spectra and Spectrum tags; is there room for some consolidation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Here are four related tags and their current question count:

- [spectroscopy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spectroscopy)  <s>(100)</s> ([101](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32750/7982))
- [spectra](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spectra)  (60)
- [spectrum](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spectrum)  (13)
- [spectrometry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spectrometry)  (10)

Here are three related questions about them:

1. As terms and as techniques, **spectrometry** is distinct from **spectroscopy**, but I am not sure we need both tags to distribute questions between. Would there be any harm in consolidating them under spectroscopy?
2. Any harm in consolidating **spectrum** and **spectra** under the plural form? ([singular/plural issue](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/520/7982))
3. Any benefits or harm to then (eventually) consolidating **spectroscopy** and **spectra**?

I think that synonymization might be the thing to do, but honestly I don't understand the options and tradeoffs to propose anything with confidence.

There is some fairly obvious re-tagging that could be done right away (I'll put a list here in a while) but I didn't want to start doing that until some discussion here first.

Answer (score 3):

All of them have a substantial number of questions, but you are right that spectrum should be consolidated under spectra. Otherwise, I think we should probably leave them be, but spectrometry needs a tag excerpt.

Comment: okay I'll add a spectrometry tag excerpt, and double check that each of those 10 questions actually meant to use it.

Comment: @uhoh I went ahead and merged spectrum into spectra and created a synonym.

Comment: excellent, thanks!